# MySqlConnection and EntityFramework shared connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I have two ways to connect to `mysql` db

```
1. using MySqlConnection 
2. using EntityFramework
```

they both implment `IDbConnection` inside

I need to share connection between them since i want to use both in single `transcation`.

Is that possible ?

Can i grap connection from entity framework context and instantiate `mySqlConnection`
and the other way orround ?

So far i checked and `MySqlConnection` can't take a connection to use inside
and `entity framework` the same, so do you see any possibility to share the connection ?

Comment: This blog should help you with EF since it will be more difficult to setup. Dapper and MySQL should be similar: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/using-entity-framework-core-and-dapper/

Comment: See [GetDbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.getdbconnection?view=efcore-7.0) method. Use: `context.Database.GetDbConnection()`.